# Rails 5 - Intermittent Error - ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (Mysql2::Error: Field 'created_at' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

need a bit of help :)

We have an intermittent error, where it says we have a null violation for one of our fields: created_at

We have several test environments, locally on our development environments we do not get this issue, but on our EC2 servers(built with AWS Elastic Beanstalk) we get the issue intermittently. 
We have not defined a default version for this as we should not need to, as Rails automatically populates this field with t.timestamps. Also we have the same created_at field in other tables without any issue.
We have recently upgraded from rails 4 to rails 5 and rails 4 everything was working.

We started to compare our environment set ups and have found the following:

- Ruby version 2.6.3 in all environments
- Gemfile.lock - all gems matching between environments
- mysql locally is:

> mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.64-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using
>   readline 5.1

and EC2 mysql is:

> mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.62, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Intermittent Error:

> ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (Mysql2::Error: Field 'created_at'
>   doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `versions` (`updated_at`)
>   VALUES ('2020-02-25 10:55:50'))
>   We are thinking about upgrading mysql - but not convinced that this is the issue.
>   And it's not easy to upgrade it in AWS Elastic Beanstalk
>   Schema.db

```
  create_table "versions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "p_id",                        limit: 4
    t.string   "name",                              limit: 255
    t.text     "description",                       limit: 16777215
    t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
```

Migration File:

```
class CreateVersions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :versions do |t|
      t.integer :p_id
      t.string :name
      t.string :description
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas on how we can debug/ fix this?

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to solve this? We've recently started to suffer the same issue with no apparent reason

Comment: Hi, nope. We stopped working on this migration. We tried to migrate from Rails 4 to rails 5.1 . So we are using Rails 4 at the moment. We found out that if you change RACK_ENV to dev environment or something different in Elastic, it starts working fine. So it's something that happen only if RACK_ENV is production. If you find something, let me know.

Comment: I just got into this error too, Rails 5.2 + MySQL

Comment: We managed to mitigate this issue in the end. We're still not completely sure what happened but it seems to be related to a race condition. We have an scheduled task that commit changes to our records and this issue only happened when this task was executed. So we added a delay after retrieving the collection we wanted to update within the task and then this issue dissapeared.

Answer (score 1):

Most of all the issue is in the cached information about the table columns. The reasons could be different:

- you run the migration on-fly without server re-start;
- you create/update records in the new table just after creating that table.

You need to reset the cache with `Version.reset_column_information` after running the migration (in the worst case put it directly into migration after `create_table`). Here's [a link to the method documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reset_column_information).

Or you can just re-start the server after running the migrations. All the cached columns information will be invalidated.

**UPDATE**

Another option I'd try is to specify Rails compatibility version in migration class (I set 4.2 here because you upgrade Rails from 4 to 5):

```rb
class CreateVersions < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
end
```

The reason is that default `timestamps` behaviour has changed in Rails 5.0 and you get different results when run migration with different Rails versions. See [this pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16481) for details. Here's the deprecation message they added:

> `timestamp` was called without specifying an option for `null`. In Rails
> 5.0, this behavior will change to `null: false`. You should manually
> specify `null: true` to prevent the behavior of your existing migrations
> from changing.

With that `[4.2]` addition it should run migration with Rails 4 compatibility and add `null: true` to your timestamp fields.

You can also add `null: true` option manually into the migration. But anyway it's highly recommended to add `[4.2]` to all your migrations before upgrading Rails version.

Comment: I believe this is not the issue, servers were restarted, table wasn't new

Comment: Hey @SergeiIakovlev, I've updated my post with more possible options that might solve your issue. Please have a look.

Comment: Thank you, i will try!